# Ninja Form doesn't work on mobile

Tags: ajax, forms, mobile, input, wordpress

I added a contact form with the Ninja Forms Wordpress plugin at my [portfolio website](http://tooi.org).

It works great, but not so much on my iPhone 4 (and probably all other mobile devices). If I tap an input field it does focus and brings up the keyboard, but doesn't show my input and stays empty. Can't figure out what the problem is..

Comment: You have `-webkit-user-select` set to `none`...not sure if that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your stylesheets has `-webkit-user-select` set to `none`. This property controls the actual Selection operation.

This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Read more in the [Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).